# Webtrends Analytics implementation - Using variables in an async tracking call/pass variable as value

Tags: web-analytics, webtrends

Does anyone here have experience doing a Webtrends implementation? According to their documentation, their asynchronous event tracking call is made by sending key-value string pairs into their tracking method, like this:

```
dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcsuri', 'page.html', 'WT.ti', 'NameOfPage');
```

However, that model does not lend well to supporting dynamic data. What I would like to do is something like this, so that I can dynamically create the key-value pairs based on the user interaction I am capturing:

```
var wtString = "'DCS.dcsuri', 'page.html', 'WT.ti', 'NameOfPage'";
dcsMultiTrack(wtString);
```

In my proof of concept, though, that does not work. The actual webtrends JS mangles the data and the call is not made. (Sifting through their code, it looks like something breaks when assigning the arguments to the Webtrends object. Anyway, I can't edit their code because then they won't support it, so I stopped investigating that end of things.)

So the question is, how can I pass the JS variable as its value? I've done a lot of searching and tried things that I thought would both work and not work: String(), .toString(), .value(), closures, and even the dreaded eval(), but to no avail.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I'm at my wits end with this one.

Comment: Oh alas, where were you in my life 2 weeks ago? :) apply() is exactly what I ended up doing and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [JavaScript's `apply` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) could help here:

```
var wtArguments = ['DCS.dcsuri', 'page.html', 'WT.ti', 'NameOfPage'];
dcsMultiTrack.apply(this, wtArguments);
```

This is effectively the same as calling:

```
dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcsuri', 'page.html', 'WT.ti', 'NameOfPage');
```